# MasterDetail list selection not retain when returning to app?

Tags: android

Title sums it up,

Using the default Master detail flow template, when loading a second activity then returning with the back button, the selected fragment detail is still visible but the list no longer has a selected item?

Comment: The second Activity deletes the item from the list used by the listview?

Comment: the item is still there but not in its activated state anymore.

Comment: Oooh.  Maybe you can save the selected item in onPause() and restore it ih onResume(). getCheckedItemPosition() and setItemChecked().

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out, the default template comes with the following (Unused?) function:

```
    private void setActivatedPosition(int position)
    {
        if (position == ListView.INVALID_POSITION)
        {
            getListView().setItemChecked(mActivatedPosition, false);
        } else
        {
            getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
        }

        mActivatedPosition = position;
    }
```

simply make you 'onListItemClick' like so:

```
 @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id)
    {
        super.onListItemClick(listView, view, position, id);
        setActivatedPosition(position); //new code
        mCallbacks.onItemSelected(LyfeListContent.ITEMS.get(position).class_id);
    }
```

and finally in the 'onResume'

```
 int pos = mActivatedPosition;

 getListView().setSelection(pos);
 getListView().performItemClick(getListView().getAdapter().getView(pos, null, null), pos, pos);
```

for anyone wondering, 'mActivatedPosition' is already defined at the top of your list fragment by the default template.